# React JS Material UI DataGrid: how to join data between multiple table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a dataGrid with React and Material UI. All data comes from table A which is structured as follows:

```
{Name: foo, Surname: Fry, Job Position: 3}
```

Then there is a table B which contains the correspondences of the various works eg:

```
{id: 3, Job: "comic"}
{id: 4, Job: "actor"}
etc...
```

how do i show "comic" in the grid instead of "3" as in the example?
A thousand thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process your data using the map() function. If your original data is in an array called people:

```
const people = [
  {name: "Alice", surname: "Alman", job:3}, 
  {name: "Bob", surname: "Briscoe", job:3}, 
  {name: "Carol", surname: "Conway", job:1}, 
  {name: "Dan", surname: "Dunne", job:2}, 
]
```

And you have the second table available

```
const jobs = [
  {id: 1, job:"Programmer"}, 
  {id: 2, job:"Actor"}, 
  {id: 3, job:"Comic"}, 
  {id: 4, job:"Manager"}, 
]
```

Then before passing the data to the grid you can do the following map to add the job title to each record:

```
const data = people.map(person => {
  const job = jobs.find(job => job.id == person.job);
  return {...person, title: job.job}
});
```

Which ends up with these values:

[{
"name": "Alice",
"surname": "Alman",
"job": 3,
"title": "Comic"
}, {
"name": "Bob",
"surname": "Briscoe",
"job": 3,
"title": "Comic"
}, {
"name": "Carol",
"surname": "Conway",
"job": 1,
"title": "Programmer"
}, {
"name": "Dan",
"surname": "Dunne",
"job": 2,
"title": "Actor"
}]